# In Google Analytics, how to compare how many views a new Article gets on its first week/month live to another article at a different time?

Tags: google-analytics

I know how to filter by date on a specific page.

But I'd like to see how many views a new article we have gets on its first week compared to another page with different publication dates on average.

Effectively creating a fake "hotness" rating that an article had coming out of the gate new and live.

**This way, I can compare how well articles do when newly released in different time periods.**

E.g.:

- In the first week of January 2017, new articles on average had 500 page views.
- In the first week of January 2018, new articles on average had 1000 page views.

Trying to avoid manual labor in get some nice reports on many, many articles.

Comment: This is a hard problem that will not be solvable completely within GA (that is, to get this data with GA only would be lots of manual labor). Do your articles have their publication date in their URL?

Comment: Is the problem that you need to compare two different documents, each during a different date range?

Comment: Yep exactly what I need

Comment: Sorry, I didn't catch that.  It looks like devnepsys has given you a way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct one-step method for this but it can be achieved in tricky way.

In Google Analytics, there is a <kbd>+Add Segment</kbd> option under "Behavior" section, for your case go to "Behavior→ Site Content → All Pages".

1. First click on <kbd>+Add Segment</kbd> then click <kbd>+New Segment</kbd>.
2. Now, click on <kbd>Conditions</kbd>.
3. Now, choose "Page Title", "contains" option and your article from drop down list, then press <kbd>OR</kbd> to add another article and save this section.

   [image: Analytic condition section]
4. Now, you will see your saved section if you also saw "All Users" section, then delete it by clicking on down arrow. Your two selected articles will be listed at the top of the list. All other pages and articles containing back-links to your selected article will also be listed below them, just ignore these other pages and articles for now.
5. In the date range, choose "Compare to" and choose different time periods as shown in image below.

   [image]
6. Now, you can compare stats of two different articles at two different time as shown in image.

   [image: Comparing stats of different Articles at a different time in Google Analytics,]

You can reuse this saved section or you can also save this report to view later but you will need to filter date each time in date range.

Comment: @envysea Does this solve your issue? Or you find a better alternative. If you find a better way to do this, don't forget to share here in the community.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  In the date range, choose "Compare to" and choose previous year.  See the image below.

[image]